# Visa red application

Tags: visas

I applied for a business Schengen visa for the first time. I was refused the visa, stating that I have no proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay or for the return to the original residence as the reason for refusal.

1. What does the refusal reason mean?
2. Can I reapply? If yes, how do I reapply (What is required?)

Comment: See the linked question above. It explains the scenarios in which you may receive this refusal and how you can address them.